# Automatically run fsck instead of booting into busybox?

Tags: boot, fsck, busybox

Is it possible to prevent the boot into busybox and the need to manually run `fsck` after a hard system shutdown (eg. due to crashed/hanging OS or hard power off) ?

The system uses an SSD. It runs Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with `grub2` boot loader.

*Note: All other questions I found only relate to the commands that need to be run in order to execute the manual filesystem check, but I could find nothing about preventing it or running it automatically without user interaction.*

Comment: need more details on this. I've done hard resest, hard shutdowns, switched off my PSU, even kicked the power cord from the wall and I've never rebooted to busybox in these cases. For the most part it can't hurt the system and with good hardware the SSD gets time to close correclty and so do HDD. In fact the only times thatI ever booted to busybox was because I messed up th system via a compile or other and no amounts of reboots would change that. Are you saying that it boots once to busyboxy and reboots to desktop after fsck? have you tried rebooting without he fsck

Comment: When the system hangs, try to switch to a tty pressing `Strg`+`Alt`+`F1` (German keyboard?), login with your user-name and password and run `sudo reboot`, this may help in many cases. I think there is no way to run the file system check automatically.

Comment: @tatsu Yes, the system reboots correctly after running fsck manually. I'm pretty sure I rebooted without running fsck the first times it occured. Yes, it did enter busybox again until I ran fsck.

Comment: try this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair tell me if the issue persists and most importantly, do you even *need*  to run `fsck`  AKA if you boot into busybox does rebooting boot to busybox *again*? And as @mook765 points out often you can fix your freeze instead of hard reseting : in an `CTRL ATL F6` session (you need to login and enable the numpad again) you can run `top`,  q to exit,  run `kill -9 0000` where 0000 is the id of the offending app, hit `CTRL ATL F7` (should be 7) to return to your desktop to see if it's unfrozen, repeat the process untill it is or it reboots.